# Breaking WorksheetFunction after using worksheet index?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I built a bunch of VBA code (fully tested and seems to be working) that includes lines such as

```
worker = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("workerlist").Range("A1"), Sheets("master").Range("A1:A20"), 0)
```

I'm trying to improve my code by referencing the sheets by index number, so I replaced `Sheets("workerlist")` with `Sheets(1)`, and the line breaks down and returns a runtime error saying it's unable to get the Match property of WorksheetFunction class.

Can the two not work together? Is there any other way to improve my referencing? When I try to look up the problem I just keep ending up with pages on using `WorksheetFunction.Index`.

Comment: Why do you think using index numbers is better than sheet names?

Comment: I'm releasing the workbook to a bunch of fairly illiterate people, so I'm trying to reduce the amount of possible issues. Index numbers would at least keep the book working if they renamed my sheets

Comment: But would break if they moved them. Using the code names would be safer. The most likely cause for the error is that Sheets(1) is not the same sheet as Sheets("workerlist"), which is why the match is now failing.

Comment: That... That's actually what I intended to do. Why would the Match fail completely instead of returning a null though? From the error it seemed like VBA couldn't find the Match function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating potential issues, not removing them.

If someone moved the workerlist worksheet from the first position, you code is broken. This is similar to what would happen in your current code if someone renamed the workerlist worksheet.

If you want to *reduce* potential issues, use the Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx). While it is possible that someone could rename the codename, it is unlikely that they could even find where to do it. It certainly is more complicated than double-clicking on a worksheet's [.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) tab and retyping or dragging the worksheet to a new position in the queue. Changing a worksheet's .CodeName is a very deliberate act.

**[Addendum:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)**

I prefer to use the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx)'s version of the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca). This is not the same as the one called by the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx). Using `Application.Match(..., ..., 0)` allows you to catch an error with a variant.

```
dim worker as variant
worker = application.Match(Sheets("workerlist").Range("A1"), Sheets("master").Range("A1:A20"), 0)
if IsError(worker) then
    'no match found; worker is Error 2042
else
    'match found; worker is a row number
end if
```

Comment: Yea that's what I intended. I got caught up trying to figure out what the problem was that I didn't realize I was using the wrong thing to begin with. Got it working after Rory pointed it out! Thanks to both of you for helping.

Comment: Please see addendum for alternative.

Comment: Ooh error handling! This is the first time I've tried to code something for other people so all this error prevention is new to me. That'll be handy for sure thanks!